# Runnable Timer not working

Tags: android

I'm using a splash screen to be displayed at the startup of my app. However, the time set does not seem to alter the duration, it runs for around 10-12 seconds.

Here's the java file

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I've set it to display for 2 seconds, what's wrong here?

Edit :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView navList;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigationdrawer);
        ArrayList<String> navArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        navArray.add("Home");
        navArray.add("Media");



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                navArray);
        navList.setAdapter(adapter);
        navList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        navList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions() | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.df);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.RIGHT| Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        loadSelection(0);
    }

    private void loadSelection(int i){
        navList.setItemChecked(i, true);

        switch (i){

            case 0 :
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, homeFragment)
                        .commit();
                actionBar.setTitle("Home");
                break;

            case 1 :
                MediaFragment mediaFragment = new MediaFragment();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, mediaFragment)
                        .commit();
                actionBar.setTitle("Media");
                break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navList)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(navList);
            }

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        loadSelection(position);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Exit the application?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Relevant part from styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Please Share your complete code with us.

Comment: Do you mean the app openes MainActivity but with more delay?

Comment: Probably won't really make a difference, but I'd suggest moving your handler block to the onResume method instead of onCreate.

Comment: I think this is because of the processes at the beginning of your `MainActivity` and the test device if old or a very slow emulator on your PC (because emulators generally are slow). Could you please also paste the code of it?

Comment: Remove the delay, and check how much times it takes-if it takes 8-10 seconds your code is working right.

Comment: I would put a log noting the time before the handler gets called and when the runnable is hit after the delay to see if there is a discrepancy there.

Comment: Updated post to include MainActivity.java and Manifest. @Stil_webmasteR - Using OP2 and Samsung S5 - not because of slow phone.

Comment: @X3Btel - When using the process given in the following link - https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/ it loads in less than half a second

Comment: I created an android app with the same code you posted, and the duration of the delay is working properly. Is that really the complete code for SplashScreenActivity.java? Are you using any animation by any chance that you omitted in your code?

Comment: @kimbaudi Nope no animation. That's the complete code

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that the image on the SplashScreen is added to the SplashScreen activity theme? Updated the original post to reflect the same

Comment: In your MainActivity.java, can you comment everything in your onCreateView() method except for `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);` and see if that helps? Also, do you have a class in your app that extends Application?

Comment: Is `@drawable/splash` an xml file? or just a .png/.jpg file?

Comment: @kimbaudi - Does not help. It is a .jpg

Comment: Nevermind, turns out the problem is due to the image size (300kb), I have redued it to 100kb and will see how things go. Thanks for your help guys!